# Usage of the word "appealing"

Tags: word-usage

Can "appealing" or "appealed" be used to express interest on something like in the following sentences ?

(1) "I find appealing the recent methods that he has been using to grow his business."

(2) "I am appealed to Dr. Smith's research on biology."

Comment: [express interest **in something**] I find the recent methods he has been using, etc, is more usual.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence uses *appealing* as an adjective, and it is correct, if a little awkward.

The second sentence is incorrect, and the word *appealed* should probably be replaced by *attracted*. Alternatively it might be rephrased as *Dr. Smith's research on biology is appealing to me*.

A decision can be appealed, for example to a higher court. A person cannot *be* appealed, but a person can *have* appealed. However, the sentence *I have appealed to Dr. Smith's research on biology* means that at some time in the past I have referred people to Dr Smith's research to prove something; it does not mean I find Dr Smith's research appealing.

Answer (score -1):

> I find appealing the recent methods that he has been using to grow his business.

The usage of 'appealing' (the adjective form) is correct here, however you also use 'appealed' (the verb form).  But the sentence is unidiomatic, as well as, poorly structured. You might consider using any one of the following alternatives:

- I find the recent methods that he has been using to grow his business appealing.
- The recent methods (that) he has been using to grow his business are appealing to me.
- The recent methods (that) he has been using to grow his business appeal to me.
- The recent methods (that) he has been using to grow his business appealed to me.

> I am appealed to Dr. Smith's research in biology.

On similar terms, 'appealed' is correct here. The sentence is grammatical. You could also go for:

- Dr. Smith's research in biology appeals to me.
- Dr. Smith's research in biology is appealing to me.
- Dr. Smith's research in biology appealed to me.

Although, any of them can be used, you must keep in mind to alter the tenses correctly to fit the context.

Comment: The recent **methods** he has been using to grow his business **are** appealing to me. The recent methods he has been using to grow his business **appeal** to me. Research **in biology**, not on biology.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections @Lambie. I absolutely didn't see what I was writing in a hurry back then.

Comment: "I am appealed to Dr. Smith's research in biology." is not correct.